# How to read Request body of an incoming Http Post request in a web api method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am trying to read the content of an incoming http post request in an API method.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Process")]
public async Task Process())
{
    //string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    NameValueCollection result = await Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
}
```

The request body is as below when I look in the fiddler. It appears as name value pairs there.

```
Request body:

name: test
total: 200
email: test@test.com
identifier: 493493
```

How can I read them in API?

`ReadAsStringAsync` gives

```
name=test&total=200&email=test@test.com&identifier=493493
```

and `ReadAsFormDataAsync` gives only keys collection which are name, total, email, identifier. But there were no values collection.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You're really missing out on the value of MVC by trying to parse through a series of name/value pairs. Create a proper model class and let MVC bind directly to it.

Comment: Actually I don't have control on the request body that will be sent to the API. They will be any name value pairs. Thank you.

Comment: How can you accept the current answer if you don't know the data that is posted? When I suggested that method, you said it wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just add a model class to collect posted data. You don't need to pick up posted data in response manually. MVC should perform it.

```
public class ProcessInput
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Total { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

**API method;**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Process")]
    public async Task Process(ProcessInput input)
    {
        //var name = input.Name;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use FormCollection:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Process")]
public async Task Process(FormCollection form)
{
    if (form.AllKeys.Contains("name")) lcName = form["name"].ToString() ?? "";
    ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to/shouldn't do it this way